# Copying file with swing JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, copy, jfilechooser, file-copying

Hello i am trying to make a simple application which will copy some file to some location.

I made two JFileChoosers first one which choose file which we want to copy and the second one which choose destination where we want to copy file. Now i dont know how to selected file to the selected location. Here is the code so far.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
private JButton btnSelectFile = new JButton("Select File"); // Kada se pritisne selectFile dugme, otvori se fileChooser.
private JLabel lbSelectFile = new JLabel("waiting"); // Ispisuje putanju do fajla koji zelimo da kopiramo.
private JButton btnWhereToCopy = new JButton("Where to copy"); // Kada pritisnemo dugme izadje file chooser da izaberemo gde zelimo da kopiramo file
private JLabel lbWhereToCopy = new JLabel("waiting"); // Stoji putanja gde zelimo da kopiramo file
private JButton btnCopyFiles = new JButton("Copy Files"); // Dugme kada se pritisne kopira fajlove
private JLabel lbIsCopied = new JLabel("waiting"); // Ako se fajl uspesno kopirao ispise se na ovoj labeli, a ako nije ispise se error.

private JPanel panel = new JPanel(); // Drzacemo pointer koji fajl zelimo da otvorimo.

private File selectedFile = null;
private File whereToCopy = null;

private ActionListener selectFile = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); // Otvorimo file chooser.

        // showOpenDialog vraca int. Moguce su opcije, CANCEL,APPROVE i ERROR. Mi moramo da proverimo koji se nama option desio od ova 3
        int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null); 

        if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // Proverimo da li imamo approve, da se file mogao lepo otvoriti, ako jeste radimo sa njim sta zelimo.
        {
            selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile(); // Stavimo pointer na fajl koji smo izabrali
            lbSelectFile.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()); // Ispisemo u labelu putanju fajla, cisto da znate sta ste izabrali.
        }
    }
};

private ActionListener selectPath = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(); // Otvaramo file chooser da izaberemo mesto gde zelimo da kopiramo file
        fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        fc.setDialogTitle("Where to copy file");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);


        if(fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            whereToCopy = fc.getSelectedFile();
            lbWhereToCopy.setText(whereToCopy.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No selection");
        }
    }
};

private ActionListener copyFile = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(selectedFile == null || whereToCopy == null)
        {
            lbIsCopied.setText("You didnt select file path");
            return;
        }

        // HOW TO COPY THIS FILES NOW
};

public MainFrame()
{
    super();
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
    setTitle("Copy Applicaton");

    // Centrira aplikaciju na centar ekrana
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(getPanel());
    pack();
}

private JPanel getPanel()
{
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // Y_AXIS, stavlja elemente po Y osi.
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));


    btnSelectFile.addActionListener(selectFile); // Obradjuje dogadjaj dugmeta.
    btnWhereToCopy.addActionListener(selectPath); // Obradjuje dogadjaj dugmeta
    btnCopyFiles.addActionListener(copyFile); // Obradjuje dogadjaje

    // Dodajemo elemente na panel, bice nam poredjane u zavisnosti koji smo layout koristili, nas slusaj ja BoxLayout
    panel.add(btnSelectFile);
    panel.add(lbSelectFile);
    panel.add(btnWhereToCopy);
    panel.add(lbWhereToCopy);
    panel.add(btnCopyFiles);
    panel.add(lbIsCopied);
    return panel;
}
```

}

I have three ActionListeners, one which gets file from JFileChooser and the second one which gets where we want to copy file. I dont know how to make third ActionListener which will copy file. Any help ?

This is what i did so far but i got error.

```
        try {
            Files.copy(selectedFile.toPath(), whereToCopy.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            lbIsCopied.setText("Error");
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        lbIsCopied.setText("Did it");
    }
```

I always get error. AccessDeniedException error.

Comment: Are you trying to move I file from one directory to another?

Comment: Have you permission to copy the file to the location. If you are on windows try running the application with administrative privilege, jsut check this once to eliminate the possibility

Comment: @paul Copy it. But i also want to know how to move it.

Comment: May I ask why you want to copy the file if your are trying to move it?

Comment: @paul Lets say i want to copy file from one folder to another, how am i going to do that ?

Comment: *"Copying file with swing JFileChooser"* Well, you don't. It's a bit like asking "How do I boil water with a saucepan lid?". The lid may be part of the solution, but it does not actually do the boiling (or even hold the water while it is boiling.) The answer to this s[ecification is more closely related to File I/O. The choosers just help us to get `File` objects representing the source and destination.

Answer (score 0):

Try the renameTo() method

```
try{
    File orginalFile = new File("path original file");
    File newFilePath = new File("path to new directory");

    if (originalFile.renameTo(newFilePath + File.Seperator + originalFile.getName())){
        System.out.println(true);
    }else {
        System.out.println(false);
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```